# Inconsistent metadata - Connecting to Firebird from SQL Server Management Studio using ODBC Driver for Firebird

Tags: sql-server, odbc, firebird, linked-server

We have a Firebird 3.0.8 database we want to add as a linked server to SQL Server Management Studio. We downloaded the [ODBC Driver for Firebird 3.3](https://www.devart.com/odbc/firebird/download.html) and created a ODBC Data-Source:

[image]

The database used in this test is a clean firebird 3.0.9 database with the default credentials (User: SYSDBA - Pwd: masterkey). We added the source as a linked server:

[image]

When trying to execute a SELECT-Query on one of the default tables of the DB

```
SELECT * FROM [TEST]...[RDB$DATABASE]
```

we get the following error:

**Original:**
Meldung 7356, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 1
Der OLE DB-Anbieter "MSDASQL" für den Verbindungsserver "TEST" hat inkonsistente Metadaten für eine Spalte bereitgestellt. Für die RDB$SECURITY_CLASS-Spalte (Kompilierzeit-Ordnungszahl 3) des RDB$DATABASE-Objekts wurde für "LENGTH" der Wert 9 zur Kompilierzeit und 31 zur Laufzeit gemeldet.

**Translated:**
Message 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'TEST' provided inconsistent metadata for a column. The RDB$SECURITY_CLASS column (compile-time ordinal 3) of the RDB$DATABASE object reported a LENGTH value of 9 at compile time and 31 at run time.

**IMPORTANT:**
Although `OPENQUERY` does not work either, we **DO NOT** want to use `OPENQUERY`, because we have to connect to the linked server externally and have to execute queries directly using a DB provider.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the ODBC driver you're using, in that it doesn't handle the Firebird metadata name columns correctly (in Firebird 3.0 and earlier, they are CHAR(31) character set UNICODE_FSS, but are also only 31 bytes long, while normally such a column would be 93 bytes long, though that doesn't explain how it arrives at a length 9 (I would sooner expect a length of 10 if it used the wrong calculation). Try a different Firebird ODBC driver, or report a bug to devart.

Comment: Alternatively, upgrade to Firebird 4.0, which changed all metadata columns to CHAR(63) character set UTF8 with the normal length in bytes (252 bytes).

Comment: It may also be a bug in OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' which receive column's properties in an inconsistent way. I have no idea what "compile time" is in their terms. ODBC has no such things.